# Basic Ruby gets.chomp

Tags: ruby

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to answer this basic question.

Write a program which asks for a person's favorite number. Have your program add one to the number, then suggest the result as a bigger and better favorite number.

This is what I have to far, but it won't convert to a number.

```
    puts "What is your favorite number?"
    number = gets.chomp
    number = number.to_i + 1
    puts "I suggest " + number + " as a bigger and better number"
```

Comment: Basic question from where? Is this homework or a Koan or something you are supposed to answer by figuring out the answer by yourself?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look more closely at the error you get:

```
What is your favorite number?
42
number.rb:4:in `+': can't convert Fixnum into String (TypeError)
    from number.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Line 4 is:

```
puts "I suggest " + number + " as a bigger and better number"
```

The problem is that Ruby won't implicitly convert `number` into a string (e.g. `"foo" + 42` is not valid in Ruby). There are a couple of solutions:

1. Call `to_s` on `number` to convert it to a string before concatenating:

   ```
   puts "I suggest " + number.to_s + " as a bigger and better number"
   ```
2. Use [Ruby string interpolation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation):

   ```
   puts "I suggest #{number} as a bigger and better number"
   ```

Option 2 is more idiomatic, I suggest using that.

Answer (score 5):

As in many other problems in ruby there are a lot of ways to do it....without the three solutions writed above there is two more:

```
puts "What is your favorite number?"
number = gets.chomp.to_i
puts "I suggest %d as a bigger and better number" % [number + 1]
```

and one wich is almost the same:

```
puts "What is your favorite number?"
number = gets.chomp.to_i
num = number + 1
puts "I suggest %d as a bigger and better number" % [num]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
print 'What is your favorite number? '
number = gets.chomp
puts "I suggest #{number.to_i + 1} as a bigger and better number"
```

There is not to much to explain about the code, but there are few things to take into account:

1. If you are rendering plain text use `'text'` instead of `"text"`. "In the double-quoted case, Ruby does more work. First, it looks for substitutions (sequences
   that start with a backslash character) and replaces them with some binary value" - Programming ruby 1.9.3
2. Always try to reduce the number of lines of code.

This things are really insignificant here, but when you are coding a big program, web page etc., it really makes a difference.

Comment: In response to #1 ... I have seen this in so many languages, and the advice is silly.   Algorithmic considerations completely dwarf any effect that string interpolation has on code.  Read up on Big O notation and use a profiler to find the real bottlenecks in code - String interpolation will never be a problem unless it is in a loop with millions of repetitions.

Comment: +1 @DGM. I've done benchmarks, and there is very little difference between `'test'` and `"test"` when there are no interpolations occurring. If there are, well, it's an acceptable cost, and is going to occur one way or another as the variables are inserted into the string, however it's done.